# Same user for multiple sites

Tags: users, domain-access, subsites, cookies

I am planning to use different server for multiple purpose.
like

Groups.eg.com

Privatecontent.eg.com

review.eg.com

etc...
I have up to 5 different subdomains and everything runs in different server and different drupal installation.

I want to use the same user base across all these sites.

I am aware that if a single drupal installation have multiple sites we achieve this using domain module.

Is there a best solution for my use case.
Because we are going to load 10k users in the site.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [Bakery module](https://www.drupal.org/project/bakery) would meet the requirements for you. It will handle single sign-on between Drupal sites on different sub-domains.

As far as performance goes, Bakery is used by drupal.org when you switch between https://www.drupal.org, https://groups.drupal.org, https://assoc.drupal.org and others.

What it doesn't do is to switch between different domains like `drupal.org` and `drupal.com`. Bakery also doesn't sync user information, if you have user fields.

For more advanced features like SSO between Drupal and non-Drupal, look at [CAS module](https://www.drupal.org/project/cas), or some of the other single sign-on solutions.